# Required help on cross join type query

Tags: sql, oracle11g

I have data in my table like

| Country |
| --- |
| Ind |
| Pak |
| Aus |

And I want to display output like

|  |
| --- |
| Ind Vs Aus |
| Ind Vs Pak |
| Aus Vs Pak |

I tried below query

```sql
with cntry as
(
select 'ind' cnt from dual union all
select 'pak' from dual union all
select 'aus' from dual
)
select x.cnt, y.cnt from cntry x
 cross join lateral
(
select cnt from cntry y
where x.cnt!=y.cnt
) y
```

But the output is not as per my requirement.

Answer (score 1):

Just join.

```
SQL> WITH
  2     cntry
  3     AS
  4        (SELECT 'ind' cnt FROM DUAL
  5         UNION ALL
  6         SELECT 'pak' FROM DUAL
  7         UNION ALL
  8         SELECT 'aus' FROM DUAL)
  9  SELECT x.cnt, y.cnt
 10    FROM cntry x JOIN cntry y ON x.cnt < y.cnt;

CNT CNT
--- ---
aus ind
aus pak
ind pak

SQL>
```